# How to create a flag with getopts to run a command

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I need help with my getopts, i want to be able to run this command ( mount command) only if i pass a flag ( -d  in this case).
below output is what i have on my script but it doesn't seem to work.

```
CHECKMOUNT=" "

while getopts ":d" opt
do
  case "$opt" in

  d) CHECKMOUNT="true" ;;

      usage >&2
      exit 1;;
    esac
   done
  shift `expr $OPTIND-1`

FS_TO_CHECK="/dev" 

if [ "$CHECKMOUNT" = "true" ] 
then
  if cat /proc/mounts | grep $FS_TO_CHECK > /dev/null; then
   # Filesystem is mounted
else
   # Filesystem is not mounted
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Here are some useful references from the factoids of the #bash channel on Freenode: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has a number of problems.

Here is the minimal list of fixes to get it working:

- `While` is not a bash control statement, it's `while`. Case **is important**.
- Whitespace **is important**: `if ["$CHECKMOUNT"= "true"]` doesn't work and should cause error messages. You need spaces around the brackets and around the `=`, like so: `if [ "$CHECKMOUNT" = "true" ]`.
- Your usage of `getopts` is incorrect, I'm guessing that you mistyped this copying an example: `While getopts :d: opt` should be: `while getopts ":d" opt`.
- Your usage of `shift` is incorrect. This should cause error messages. Change this to: `shift $((OPTIND-1))` if you need to shift `OPTIND`.
- The bare text *unknocn flag* seems like a comment, precede it with `#`, otherwise you'll get an error when using an unknown option.
- There is no `usage` function. Define one, or change `usage` in your `\?)` case to an `echo` with usage instructions.

Finally, if your script only requires a single optional argument, you might also simply process it yourself instead of using `getopt` - the first argument to your script is stored in the special variable `$1`:

```
if [ "$1" = "-d" ]; then
    CHECKMOUNT="true"
elif [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    usage >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks but I have multiple options in my script so I can't use what you provided . And the points you noted - I fixed those but still no luck

Comment: what problems do you see now? It's likely that you still have a syntax error

Comment: You also lack the `*)` case label before the `usage` invocation. And you still have a Useless Use of Cat (see previous question).

Comment: That still doesn't solve my problem, i just need to know ifi `if [ "$CHECKMOUNT "= "true" ] 
then
  if cat /proc/mounts | grep $FS_TO_CHECK > /dev/null; then
   # Filesystem is mounted
else
   # Filesystem is not mounted
  fi
fi` is even right. or if i am passing correctly.

Comment: did you copy that command from your script? because you still have a whitespace issue: ` [ "$CHECKMOUNT "= "true" ]` is wrong. See my answer: you need spaces around the `=`, and no space after `CHECKMOUNT`: `if [ "$CHECKMOUNT" = "true"` ]

Comment: Yes that's how it is. Can you confirm if i am passing "CHECKMOUNT"="" correctly, or should it be "CHECKMOUNT"="false"

Comment: observe the **space** around the `=`: `if [ "$CHECKMOUNT" = "true" ]`